# python extra value added to the variable

Tags: python, linux, debian

i am running a python zabbix trapper script running on two servers and it works on one of them fine. It runs every 30 seconds. this is the part of the code which reads the time_wait status from "ss"

```
file_log = "/tmp/tcpstate.log"
proc = open(file_log,"a")

file = "/var/log/safesquid/safesquid/performance/performance.log"
time_wait_cmd = subprocess.Popen("ss -o state time-wait | grep webcache | wc -l",shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
ssquid_time = time_wait_cmd.communicate()[0]
proc_string = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S") + " " + "Time_WAIT: " + ssquid_time  + "\n"
proc.write(proc_string)
proc.close()
```

Output from server1: (OK)

```
01-05-12 17:40:50 Time_WAIT: 286
01-05-12 17:41:20 Time_WAIT: 251
01-05-12 17:41:50 Time_WAIT: 366
01-05-12 17:42:20 Time_WAIT: 335
01-05-12 17:42:50 Time_WAIT: 287
01-05-12 17:43:20 Time_WAIT: 375
01-05-12 17:43:51 Time_WAIT: 386
01-05-12 17:44:21 Time_WAIT: 383
```

Output from Server2: (PROBLEM)

```
01-05-12 17:44:03 Time_WAIT: 368
01-05-12 17:44:32 Time_WAIT: 388
01-05-12 17:45:01 Time_WAIT: 0
01-05-12 17:45:01 Time_WAIT: 339
01-05-12 17:45:31 Time_WAIT: 311
01-05-12 17:46:00 Time_WAIT: 400
01-05-12 17:46:01 Time_WAIT: 0
01-05-12 17:46:29 Time_WAIT: 411
01-05-12 17:46:58 Time_WAIT: 448
```

since its being called every 30seconds, i am not sure why on Server2 its gets "0" value and then immediately reads the correct value.

ANy ideas why this is happening?

Comment: You might want to check out [the `with` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) for working with files - it's more readable and handles closing the file for you - even on exceptions.

Comment: thanks for the advice Lattyware, but the problem i think is the subprocess command cause i am just printing to file for diagnosis...

Comment: I'm not suggesting that that was the cause of the issue, just a suggestion in general for making your code more Pythonic.

Comment: I'm not so sure it's the sub-process command causing trouble. The fact that two separate lines are being written makes me suspect it's actually being run twice. Note, it's only being called twice every two runs. Is there a crontab you can share? And the line beginning with `file =` is redundant in this example, isn't it?

Comment: really sorry guys...there was a cronjob running.....

Answer (score 0):

Is either process receiving signals?  That could cause a syscall to terminate earlier than anticipated.